# Finding Mersenne numbers in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to find the first 10 Mersenne prime numbers in Prolog and I have implemented the following:

```
% Define a predicate to check if a number is prime.
is_prime(N) :-
    N > 1,
    \+ has_divisor(N, 2).

% Define a predicate to check if N has a divisor other than 1 and itself.
has_divisor(N, D) :-
    D =< sqrt(N),
    0 is N mod D,
    D > 1,
    !.

% Define a predicate to check if a number is a Mersenne prime.
is_mersenne_prime(P) :-
    is_prime(P),
    Mersenne is 2^P - 1,
    is_prime(Mersenne).

% Find the first 10 Mersenne prime numbers.
find_mersenne_primes(N, Count) :-
    Count > 0,
    is_mersenne_prime(N),
    write(N), write(' 2^'), write(N), write('-1'), nl,
    NewCount is Count - 1,
    NewN is N + 1,
    find_mersenne_primes(NewN, NewCount).
    
find_mersenne_primes(_, 0).

main :-
    write('Calculating the first 10 Mersenne prime numbers:'), nl,
    find_mersenne_primes(2, 10).

% Start the program when the Prolog file is consulted.
:- initialization(main).
```

I have run it in SWI Prolog portable, but I got the following error:

```
% d:path compiled 0.00 sec, 7 clauses
Calculating the first 10 Mersenne prime numbers:
2 2^2-1
3 2^3-1
Warning: d:35: Initialization goal failed
```

The prime function works correctly, but I have doubts about the find_Mersenne function, how can I do so that it prints the first 10 prime evaluated numbers?

Comment: "*The prime function works correctly*" - `?- is_prime(9).` says true but `?- 9 is 3 * 3.` and therefore is not prime. The code appears to be testing for odd numbers, not prime numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix both `is_prime/1` and `find_mersenne_primes/2`.
For the former, you can adopt a Prolog conversion, for example, of the code you can find in the [wikipedia page about primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Python).

```
is_prime(N):-
    N =< 3,
    N > 1, !.
is_prime(N):-
    (0 is N mod 2 ; 0 is N mod 3), !,
    false.
is_prime(N):-
    L is sqrt(N),
    is_prime_loop(N, 5, L+1), !.
is_prime_loop(N, I, Max):-
    I < Max,
    (   (0 is N mod I ; 0 is N mod I+2) ->  
        !, false ;
    is_prime_loop(N, I+6, Max)).
is_prime_loop(_, I, Max):-
    I >= Max, !.
```

then you also need

```
find_mersenne_primes(N, Count) :-
    Count > 0,
    NewN is N + 1,
    find_mersenne_primes(NewN, Count).
find_mersenne_primes(_, 0) :- !.
```

below the first `find_mersenne_primes/2` clause.